# Changing the order of the integration $\int_{-1}^1\int_{|y|}^1(x+y)^2dxdy$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> How can you find the new limits if you change the order of the integration
>
> $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1\int_{|y|}^1(x+y)^2dxdy$

I tried;

$\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1\int_{|y|}^1(x+y)^2dxdy=\displaystyle\int_{-1}^0\int_{|y|}^1(x+y)^2dxdy+\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_{|y|}^1(x+y)^2dxdy$ $(\bigstar)$

First integral on the RHS is;

$\displaystyle\int_{-1}^0\int_{|y|}^1(x+y)^2dxdy=\displaystyle\int_{-1}^0\int_{-y}^1(x+y)^2dxdy$

because $y$ goes from $-1$ to $0$, therefore its absolute value is $-y$

Now changing the order:

if $-y\le x\le 1$ then $-x\le y\le ?$, but we know that the upper limit of $y$ is $0$, so $-x\le y\le 0$ then,

$-y\le x\le 1$ and $-x\le y\le 0$ gives $0\le x\le 1$ and our new integral is

$\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_{-x}^0(x+y)^2dydx$

$2nd$ integral on the RHS of $(\bigstar)$ can be done in a similar way and we get

$\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_0^{x}(x+y)^2dydx$ and their sum is

$\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_{-x}^0(x+y)^2dydx+\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_0^{x}(x+y)^2dydx=\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_{-x}^{x}(x+y)^2dydx$

Is my approach correct ?

How would you solve this ? I kind of think that this is not the usual way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try and draw a picture of the area over which you integrate. This might give you an idea of how to change the order.

Comment: @Jeroen Ok I got the area, which is a triangle. $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$ ans $y$ is bounded by $y=-x$ and $y=x$, but would you also draw a picture in a more difficult example ?

Comment: In general, the problem can be a bit tough, requiring knowing where various boundary curves have extrema. Even there, drawing a picture will help to see whether you are falling into a trap. For instance, try changing the order of integration in $\int_{x=-3}^{3}\int_{y=-6}^{x^4-4x^2}(x^2+y^2)dy \, dx$. Yes, you can easily invert the function, but you might naively omitthe region near $(0,-1)$ unless you are very careful.  A picture makes that trap obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{\verts{y}}^{1}\pars{x + y}^{2}\,\dd x\,\dd y:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
> \int_{-1}^1\int_{\verts{y}}^{1}\pars{x + y}^{2}\,\dd x\,\dd y}
> =\left.\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x + y}^{2}\,\dd x\,\dd y\,
> \right\vert_{\,x\ >\ \verts{y}}
> \\[3mm]&=\left.\int_{0}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\pars{x + y}^{2}\,\dd y\,\dd x\,
> \right\vert_{\,\verts{y}\ <\ x}
> =\left.\int_{0}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\pars{x + y}^{2}\,\dd y\,\dd x\,
> \right\vert_{\,-x\ <\ y\ <\ x}
> \end{align}

Since $\ds{0\ <\ x\ <\ 1}$:
\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
\int_{-1}^1\int_{\verts{y}}^{1}\pars{x + y}^{2}\,\dd x\,\dd y}
=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{-x}^{x}\pars{x + y}^{2}\,\dd y\,\dd x
=\int_{0}^{1}\left.{\pars{x + y}^{3} \over 3}
\,\right\vert_{\,y\ =\ -x}^{\,y\ =\phantom{-}x}\quad\dd x
\\[3mm]&={8 \over 3}\int_{0}^{1}x^{3}\,\dd x={8 \over 3}\,{1 \over 4}
\end{align}

> $$\color{#66f}{\large%
> \int_{-1}^1\int_{\verts{y}}^{1}\pars{x + y}^{2}\,\dd x\,\dd y}
> =\color{#66f}{\large{2 \over 3}}\approx 0.6667
> $$